# Rotate a group of 6 objects to align 3 points (each on a different object) on a plane

Tags: modeling, objects, snapping, groups

I have 6 rectangular blocks that I want to rotate as a group so the bottom 3 vertices (each are on a different block) end up on the same plane; in this case the global X-Y plane. How can I do this?
See picture below.
[image]
I am completely new to Blender, so please be clear with the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Select all blocks and enter edit mode (TAB), change pivot point to active element.
[image]

[image]

then enter vertex select mode (number one on horizontal numbers on keyboard above Q)
Select all verts and click on one of the bottom verts so you have that one as active. Press 1 on number pad (right numbers). Use move tool (G) and right after press Z to move blocks down to where you want. Now while still in front view (that you set by pressing 1 on number pad) press R to rotate your blocks until one of the other 2 verts are aligned with the plain. Then switch to side view (number 3 on your number pad) and rotate again until 3rd vert is aligned

Comment: After I snap one of the bottom vertices to the corner of the plane, how do I rotate and snap another vertex? For the third and final bottom vertex, how do I rotate about an axis between the first two vertices, so the third vertex snaps to the plane?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that I understand your question but I believe you may be able to achieve what you want by simply scaling the vertices in question to 0 on a single axis, by following these steps.

1. Ensure your Pivot Point is set to Median (you can also do this with the full-stop key):

[image]

2. Select the object(s) containing the blocks and hit Tab to enter Edit Mode
3. Make sure you are in vertice select mode by pressing 1 on the number **row** (**not** the number **pad**) of your keyboard, or using the following selection in the top-left corner:

[image]

4. Select each of the vertices (shift left-click) that you would like to 'end up on the same plane; in this case the global X-Y plane.'
5. With the vertices selected, press S to enter scale mode, X, Y or Z to select an axis, 0, then enter.

This will move each of the selected vertices so that they are in the same position on the selected axis. The position will be an average of where each of the different vertices were on the selected axis, prior to the scale operation.